# Would an unclosed javascript in the header prevent another javascript from working in the body?

Tags: html

We have a web content management system and I can't get to the header portion of the page.  I can see it in the full page when debugging, but can't upload a revised file.

In the header, there's a portion of the same Javascript - about six lines, but it's truncated and not closed.

In the body, I have the full slideshow Javascript which works great in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome. Strangely it even works in IE8 on my PC, but not on the other 10 pcs I've tested it on.

The only thing I can edit/save changes is the body portion of the page.

I originally thought javascripts had to be in the header, but clearly not since the body script is working in the other browsers.  Do you know though if IE8 requires the script to be in the header?

I think the problem is defintitely 1) a partially coded, unclosed script in the header and/or 2) perhaps javascripts have to be in the header for IE8?

In that case, I would need the remote server company to post the javascript that's currently in the body into the header.

Thanks for your help,
Debby

Answer (score 1):

Script elements are allowed in many places and MSIE doesn't impose any additional requirements.

If a script element is unclosed, then everything until the next `</script>` will be treated as part of that script. If that includes HTML then it will error and stop running that script.

Answer (score 1):

Script tags doesn't have to be in the head section. You should place them there unless you have a good reason not to, but it works just fine to have script tags in the body also.

The unclosed tag is quite likely to cause problems. At worst the browser will just ignore everything until it finds a closing tag for it. If you can't get rid of it you should at least put an empty script tag first in the code that you can control.

Answer (score 0):

There are no limitations on where you keep your code, it is common practice that included javascript libraries (such as jQuery, mooTools, etc) go in the `<head>` element, while custom javascript goes in the end of the `<body>` element, because it will only run after all the other things in the page were already downloaded.

The reason for your problem is probably the unclosed `<script>` tag in the head. It makes everything until the closing `</script>` tag as script, even critical HTML. Which makes the page render incorrectly, and your javascript to throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

Close the  tag and resume with your own body

```
</script>
</head>
<body>
//... your code
```

Comment: Or Better solution! Contact the company that you are dealing with that is causing the bad code in the header. Make them fix it! Unless you test on an exhausted number of setups you cannot be 100% on how unclosed script tag will affect each page. For consistency you should get the root problem fixed and not attempt to 'hack' a fix into _still broken_ code.